# changing a columns data within irb for a heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord, rails-activerecord, irb

I have an app on heroku which I need to alter.

My app is a ruby on rails app and I am using the devise gem for sign in and the cancancan gem for authority and abilites for users and admins.

My local environment for development is using sqlite and the heroku production side is using postgres.

When I deploy my app to heroku, none of the database content transfers over. And so i need to manually use the irb active record that heroku gives for the app so that i can change the role column in the Users Table to make "role:nil" change to "role:admin"

this is what it looks like currently inside my heroku irb

```
User.find(1)
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, email: "tutu@tutu.com", created_at: "2017-11-16 14:58:23", updated_at: "2017-11-16 14:58:23", role: nil>
irb(main):009:0> User.find_by_role(nil)
```

How do I use the irb console to change the role column from "nil" to "admin"?

What commands should I use inside of irb to change the User column "role" from "role:nil" to "role:admin"?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious what your question actually is. Try editing your question so it includes a question.

Comment: I highly encourage developers to use the same database locally which is used in production.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for one of

```
User.where(role: nil).update_all(role: "admin") # Updates all users which have a nil role.
```

OR

```
User.find(1).update(role: "admin") # Just updates one user record.
```